# Filter rdd lines by values in fields Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv that has the following structure:

> header,header,header,header,header
>   val1,  val2,  val3,  val4,  val5
>   val1,  val2,  null,  val4,  val5
>   val1,  val2,  val3,  null,  val5

What I need to do is filter out the header and the lines of data that contain null values at particular locations(it is OK to have a null at val3 but not val4).  I made an rdd and split the lines on the commas, my hope was to access each line like an index location of an array.    But I can not find out how to do the comparison.  I can extract fields with:

> rdd.map(values=>(values(2))

How do you do the comparison?  Particularly the "does not contain".  I would think there is a comparison method available or does this problem require a tuple  and !contain?

Comment: Is there any constraint that, you will need to use RDD? If not I think, you can use DataFrame. DataFrame API of SPARK is most suitable for handling operation on CSV files.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you have defined a type for wrapping those values, let's say:

```
case class Record(val1: String, val2: Option[String], val3: String, val4: Option[String])

val rdd: RDD[Record] = ...
rdd.filter(record => record.val2.isDefined && record.val4.isDefined)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with `DataFrame`s instead of `RDD`s you would use `filter` along with boolean `Column` operations.

Suppose neither `val4` nor `val5` should be null.

If your csv looks like this:

```
evan@vbox ~ > cat dat_1.csv
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
val1,val2,,val4,val5
val1,val2,val3,,val5
```

Then your code would look like:

```
scala> val dat_1 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("dat_1.csv")
dat_1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [header1: string, header2: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> dat_1.show
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|header1|header2|header3|header4|header5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   null|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   null|   val5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+


scala> data1.filter($"header4".isNotNull && $"header5".isNotNull).show
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|header1|header2|header3|header4|header5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   null|   val4|   val5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Otherwise if your data looks like this:

```
evan@vbox ~ > cat dat_2.csv
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
val1,val2,null,val4,val5
val1,val2,val3,null,val5
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
scala> val dat_2 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("dat_2.csv")
dat_2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [header1: string, header2: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> dat_2.show
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|header1|header2|header3|header4|header5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   null|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   null|   val5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+


scala> dat_2.filter($"header4" =!= "null" && $"header5" =!= "null").show
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|header1|header2|header3|header4|header5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   val1|   val2|   val3|   val4|   val5|
|   val1|   val2|   null|   val4|   val5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Null values in an input file are not represented by the way it is represented in your file:

```
header,header,header,header,header
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5
val1, val2, null, val4, val5
val1, val2, val3, null, val5
```

It should be something like:

```
header,header,header,header,header
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5
val1, val2, null, val4, val5
val1, val2, val3,, val5
```

Solution: Usage of mapPartitionsWithIndex to drop the 1st iterator for 0th index will filter the header from your input file, while the Usage of != "" on the 4th field will filter out the 3rd line

```
**scala>** sc.textFile("/User/VJ/testfile").
mapPartitionsWithIndex((x,y) => if (x==0) y.drop(1) else y).
filter(x=>x.split(",")(3) != "" ).
take(5).foreach(println)
```

Required Output:

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5
val1, val2, null, val4, val5
```

Example here at
https://tips-to-code.blogspot.com/2018/08/nulls-in-scala-spark.html

Thanks,
Vishal.